# ActionBar BUG: List mode navigation not visible after using SearchView

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

Project demonstrating this bug: https://github.com/smarek/ActionBar-Navigation-Bug

---

Bugreport on [b.android.com](http://b.android.com) : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=51449

---

I'm currently facing an issue with ActionBar.

Let's have a ViewPager+PagerTitleStrip and 3 Fragments.
User flow:

- Open application
- First Fragment has set navigation mode to NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST

  - Other Fragments has NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD
- All Fragments has options menu item with SearchView
- Go to second or third and open search (click on search item)
- Close search view or not (you can just swipe back to previous fragment)
- Go to first fragment, and see, there is no NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST
- On first fragment open search and close it
- Navigation list is visible again

**Adding just the code of MainActivity and layout the project is standard Android Application Project, minSdk 11, when creating main activity, select blank activity and  swipe views + title strip**

**layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!--
    This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
    titles for adjacent pages.
    -->

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**com/example/project/MainActivity.java**

```
// imports ommited

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public static final int MENU_SEARCH = -1;
        protected MenuItem searchItem;
        protected SearchView mSearchView;

        public DummySectionFragment() {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        /*
        * Initializing menu items, adding only searchItem (aka SearchView in actionview)
        */
        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            mSearchView = new SearchView(getActivity().getActionBar()
                    .getThemedContext());
            searchItem = menu
                    .add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SEARCH, Menu.NONE, "Search")
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search)
                    .setActionView(mSearchView)
                    .setShowAsActionFlags(
                            MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                                    | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return textView;
        }

        // Using setUserVisibleHint to operate with actionbar
        // (navigation mode) and visibility of option menu items
        // if isVisibleToUser, we're doing setup for current Fragment
        @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
            if (isVisibleToUser) {
                    // setting navigation mode according to fragment
                ActionBar ab = getActivity().getActionBar();
                int mode = 0;
                    // ARG_SECTION_NUMBER is argument with numbers 1, 2, 3
                switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
                default:
                case 1:
                    mode = ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST;
                            // Simple adapter added to spinner, to be visible
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getActivity(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                            new String[] { "A", "B", "C" });
                    ab.setListNavigationCallbacks(spinnerArrayAdapter,
                            new OnNavigationListener() {

                                @Override
                                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(
                                        int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                    break;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    mode = ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD;
                    break;
                }
                getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(mode);
            } else {
                    // resetting navigation mode
                if (getActivity() != null
                        && getActivity().getActionBar() != null)
                    getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(
                            ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            }
        }
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have heard some reports of problems with fragments in a `ViewPager` not participating correctly with the action bar, so I am not terribly surprised that you are encountering issues here. Search http://b.android.com to see if anyone else has reported similar behavior. I also suggest that you upload a complete sample project somewhere that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for attention, I've uploaded whole project to github, and links are in question. I haven't found similar issue yet, but I will continue searching.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm convinced this is a bug, I've filled a bug report, and attached link to the top of my question.

Comment: Sorry, haven't had a chance to look at this yet. Will try to get to it soonish.

Comment: Well, I can reproduce the bug given your sample app. Note that if you tap on the search view on the first page, before swiping to the next, the list navigation works properly when you return to the first page. It definitely feels like a bug.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Great news, I was little bit afraid, that the problem is  on my devices only. So now what remains, is to find the reason and then (if possible) workaround.

Comment: If all fragments have the SearchView option, maybe you can add it from the Activity instead of the Fragment?

Comment: @nicopico will it make difference?

Comment: I made a quick test, and it does not seems to change anything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Bug***

I am posting this just to point the discussion in the direction of the bug.

The bug is more related to the `SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW` flag. Once you remove the flag, everything will work perfectly. It is most probably a bug but once again I am not sure if there is a rational explanation.

***Solution*** (not really)

When you're creating the menu item in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, remove the *ORed* `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW`

Simply, change this

```
searchItem = menu
.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SEARCH, Menu.NONE, "Search")
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search)
.setActionView(mSearchView)
.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
    | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```

to

```
searchItem = menu
.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SEARCH, Menu.NONE, "Search")
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search)
.setActionView(mSearchView)
.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

***Bug without viewpager***

I have forked the project and here it is without the viewpager with the same behaviour [ActionBar-Navigation-Bug](https://github.com/sherifelkhatib/ActionBar-Navigation-Bug)

Comment: @MarekSebera Did you try his solution with your own project?

Comment: @MarekSebera Thanks for update, this ensures that others do  not spend time trying this out.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib oh, it works under certain conditions, i will investigate and get back to you, but on the other hand, searchview is not filling whole width of actionbar on expanding.

Comment: This workaround fixes the bug, but it also seems to alter the behavior of the back button.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when the SearchView had the SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW flag set. My workaround was to expand and collapse the MenuItem of the SearchView after switching to the NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST );
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled( false );
searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
```

It is kind of dirty but it did the job for me.

Btw... The same bug and solution also applies to ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: @Moritz this workaround cause opening keyboard on fast galaxy s4 while executing. Manual closing doesn't help

Comment: This one did work for me. I'm concerned about Lazy Beard's comment, but I did notice that this bug doesn't happen on 4.4 for me so I've excluded the workaround to 4.2 and below.

Comment: To clarify, bug also doesn't happen on 4.3 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got round this bug:

First I made the MenuItem global in the activity:

```
private  MenuItem searchItem;
```

In the activity I had the following method:

```
public void hideSearch() 
{
     MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);
}
```

Then in the onCreateView() method of the fragment I call this method, just before returning the view. My spinner then stopped being hidden. To be honest, Im not sure why this works, but it did for me.